# I have URL rewriting in my asp.net web solution how can I set startup url for non existent URL in VS2010?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have URL rewriting in my asp.net web solution defined how can I set startup url for non existent page URL in VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the web project, open the Properties page.
2. Go to the Web tab.
3. Select Start URL for the Start Action and enter the full URL that you want to use.